# Using Sprig's live search but show all entries first

Tags: plugin-sprig

I want to display all results in the games section to start with, then once you search, it shows the filtered results. Sprig's starting point I think assumes that you're showing nothing, like a normal search box.

With the code below, it shows all results to start with - but once there's a search query, it shows the filtered results, then also ALL of the results underneath those. What do I need to change to show all results first and REPLACE them with the filtered results after searching?

It's something to do with the s-target stuff I think. The original loop gets 'moved' into #results when you search, but as I don't understand how Sprig works so I don't really know why it's doing it

```
{% set queryParams = {} %}
{% set relatedParams = ['and'] %}

{# This is where the query logic is -combining category filters and text search etc #}

{% if sprig.include %}
    <select sprig s-target="#results" name="verdict" id="verdict">
        {# loop through options #}
    </select>
    <select sprig s-target="#results" name="rating" id="rating">
        {# loop through options #}
    </select>
    <select sprig s-target="#results" name="platform" id="platform">
        {# loop through options #}
    </select>
    <input sprig s-trigger="keyup changed" s-target="#results" type="search" name="title" id="title" />
    <div id="results"></div>
{% endif %}

{% if queryParams %}
    {% set entries = craft.entries(queryParams).orderBy('score').all() %}
    {% for entry in entries %}
        {{ entry.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {% set entries = craft.entries.section('games').orderBy('title').all() %}
    {% for entry in entries %}
        {{ entry.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the example from the [Sprig Cookbook](https://putyourlightson.com/sprig-cookbook#search), it looks like the results container should live outside the `sprig.isInclude`:

```
{% if sprig.isInclude %}
    <select sprig s-target="#results" name="verdict" id="verdict">
        {# loop through options #}
    </select>
    <select sprig s-target="#results" name="rating" id="rating">
        {# loop through options #}
    </select>
    <select sprig s-target="#results" name="platform" id="platform">
        {# loop through options #}
    </select>
    <input sprig s-trigger="keyup changed" s-target="#results" type="search" name="title" id="title" />
{% endif %}

<div id="results">
{% if queryParams %}
    {% set entries = craft.entries(queryParams).orderBy('score').all() %}
    {% for entry in entries %}
        {{ entry.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {% set entries = craft.entries.section('games').orderBy('title').all() %}
    {% for entry in entries %}
        {{ entry.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that was it. Can't believe I didn't try that before.

Comment: Updated the answer to use the new `sprig.isInclude` syntax as of beta 15.